# different nav bar for different pages in react

Tags: reactjs

For my application, I have a nav bar which has different functionality for different pages. ie. 1 page has a map and the search will search for addresses and another page has a list and the search bar will filter the list. There are also different buttons on each page too.

What's the best way to implement something like this in react? I've thought about creating a different search bar component for every page and just rendering a different one for each route but I don't have enough experience in React to go ahead with that decision. Is there a more efficient alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Navbar component named something like NavBarController. While calling the navbar controller component pass in the "Type" as prop. Type should be a state and should change depending on the page the user is on.

```
<NavBarController type={1}></NavBarController>
```

You would just create a few different NavBars and then NavBarController will handle whichever navbar you want to display out of your multiple navbars.

Your NavBarController will return something like this:

```
return (props.type===1?<NavBarHome/>
:props.type===2?<NavBarMap/>
:props.type===3?<NavBarList/>)
```